# Flash "Double Typing" problem

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I just wanted to ask whether this is a familiar phenomenon. We have a small flash application that has an text box.

under OSX Lion, with flash < 10.3.*.* it works fine

with OSX Lion and Flash 10.3.*.* every character typed to it, appears twice.

Same application...

Anyone heard of anything remotely similar?

Comment: That sounds odd. Maybe Flash Player 10.3 triggers the key-up event twice? How does it behave on other OS's?

Comment: Ask Jobs - you're holding it wrong.  :D   http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/apple-responds-over-iphone-4-reception-issues-youre-holding-th/

Comment: hehe... Jobs isn't returning my phone calls. 10.3 works well on the previous OSX, Snow Leopard. It's the combo of Lion and 10.3 that causes this weirdness

Comment: I don't think the double tap issue is listed, but you may find more information here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/905/cpsid_90508.html#products .  I'm pretty sure the formal Adobe stance is "Don't upgrade to Lion yet."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a commercial client application that uses Flash for input and output.  We are seeing this issue also with Mac OS 10.7.0, Flash plugin 10.3.185.5 .

Our application plays a flash swf file using the Webkit view object.  It turns out that this is the configuration that exhibits the bug on OS 10.7.

We were able to fix the bug by compiling our application to target only 64 bit Intel platforms, instead of building a universal binary.

This fixes the bug, but we are going to have to change our installer to have both a 64 bit binary for OS 10.7 and a universal binary for earlier versions of OS 10.

Adobe says their bug is fixed, no work on when they will release an official build containing the fix.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2935794

Comment: Adobe says it is released now: "This issue has been fixed in Flash Player 11 public release build"

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in a Cocoa App that was using a flex component. We solved it by compiling the cocoa app in 64bits.
matthieu

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is to wait for updates from Adobe or OSX Lion...

Comment: In the meantime you may vote for the bug in Adobe bugbase: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2927890. Let's hope they fix it sooner than later.